# Generating a sequence number which survives service restarts

Tags: architecture, sequence

I have an application which sends events to the clients. These events should be tagged with a ordered sequence number. The requirement is that event `b`, which happened after `a`, has a sequence number which is greater than the one for `a`.

My idea was to create a 128 bytes sequence as following:

```
<timestamp when service was initiated><long which is incremented for each event; initially 0>
```

The advantage of this is that when a service is restarted, we can remain sequence order.

This should work, except if the service was restarted faster than 1 millisecond.

How do I cope with that? Should I care about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep this sequence, you want to persist some information (in this case a sequence number).

A simple way to do that would be to write in a file and start from the last sequence number when the program restarts. Consequently, a timestamp would not even be needed.

You can still keep the timestamp to make your file some kind of log if needed. It really depends on the usage of your application.